# Video editing software that allows side-by-side frame editing

Tags: windows, video-editing

I have a bunch of mpg files and I would like to compile them into one video where I play clips from the individual files side-by-side at certain points.  Is there an editing software that allows me to do this?  I would also like to overlay text and insert still images and sound.

Answer (score 2):

The video editor built into [Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org) modelling toolkit can do exactly this as can be seen in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6BKQVbxw8I) instructional video.

It can also:

- Split screen and picture in picture videos
- "Green Screen" to substitute another video or still for a plain colored background.
- Video stabilization to remove or reduce shake
- Accept multiple video formats to produce a single video
- Multi-track both sound and video
- Insert still images as variable length shots in the video
- Edit, Mix and Overlay sounds
- Insert Captions that are any of Plain Text, Overlays, Animated Plain Text, Animated Overlays, 3D Text, [Animated 3D Text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPPQR3L6BGI) *(also as overlays)*, Subtitles, etc.
- Add transitions, fades & effects to video footage.
- You can even do things like the [flying, spinning video frame](https://youtu.be/Cg5uT6mrXCY) .
- Of course the rest of Blender can be used 3D model, render and animate *there is a surprise*

[This](http://www.blendtuts.com/video_editing) half hour tutorial on Blender Video editing is just one of the ones that I found that was well worth watching.

Blender is Cross Platform, Free - Gratis and Open Source and there is a lot of online tutorials, community support, etc. - *Just in case I sound too much like an advert I had better say that I am an occasional **user** of Blender no more.*

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) provides a light-weight way to do what you want. It's another cross-platform tool and is free. It is a command-line utility (i.e. no point-and-click user interface) but the method for creating side-by-side videos looks simple enough:

[Compare two videos side by side using ffmpeg](http://ianfeather.co.uk/compare-two-webpagetest-videos-using-ffmpeg/).

Adding text overlays and sound in ffmpeg is possible, but I'm sure you'll find it much more convenient to use ffmpeg just to produce the bare side-by-side sequences, and then use your favourite graphical video editor to insert these into your main video and add text overlays and audio.